# What value is needed to keep average above a certain value?

Tags: mean

My watch keeps track of the number of active calories I burn each day. My weekly mean daily calories burned by Saturday last week was 1004. However by Sunday night, my weekly average ended up being 997 and I was disappointed not to keep average above 1000. How could I have calculated what total I needed on Sunday to keep average calories burned above 1000 for the week?

Comment: (1) How many calories had you burned by Saturday night? (2) How many did you want to burn for the week ending Sunday night?  (3) Subtract.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to burn at least an average of $y$ calories per day in $N$ days, and after $k$ days you burned an average of $x$ calories per day (where $k<N$). Then you want to burn an average of $z$ calories per day in the remaining $N-k$ days such that,
$$
\frac{k x + (N-k) z}{N} \ge y,
$$
which can be rearranged to give
$$
z \ge\frac{N y - k x}{N-k}.
$$

In your specific case, $k=6,$ $N=7,$ $x=1004,$ and $y=1000.$